# iOS My APP is crash in main how to find the error?

Tags: ios, objective-c, symbolicatecrash

```
0 libsystem_kernel.dylib    __pthread_kill + 8

1 libsystem_pthread.dylib   pthread_kill + 112

2 libsystem_c.dylib abort + 140

3 libc++abi.dylib   __cxa_bad_cast + 0

4 libc++abi.dylib   std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 44

5 libc++abi.dylib   __cxxabiv1::exception_cleanup_func(_Unwind_Reason_Code, _Unwind_Exception*)

6 libobjc.A.dylib   _objc_exception_destructor(void*)

7 CoreFoundation    -[NSException initWithCoder:]

8 KZW_iPhone2   _UmengSignalHandler + 128

9 libsystem_platform.dylib  _sigtramp + 36

10 libobjc.A.dylib  (anonymous namespace)::AutoreleasePoolPage::pop(void*) + 836

11 FrontBoardServices   ___FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 44

12 FrontBoardServices   -[FBSSerialQueue _performNext] + 176

13 FrontBoardServices   -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 56

14 CoreFoundation   ___CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 24

15 CoreFoundation   ___CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 540

16 CoreFoundation   ___CFRunLoopRun + 744

17 CoreFoundation   CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 424

18 UIKit    -[UIApplication _run] + 652

19 UIKit    UIApplicationMain + 208

20 My_iPhone2   main (main.m:14)
```

Answer (score 3):

Ok, here goes heavy idea - have you tried using breakpoints at flow of program? Open the sixth tab (Breakpoint Navigator) in your project explorer, in the bottom left corner tap +(plus) icon -> Add exception breakpoint -> Done. This will add an exception handler that will stop your app on the very method call that crashes the app.

In my case most of times more than(80%), I found the correct error using this trick. hope this one will also work for you. All the best.

Comment: thank you very much .the problem is when i running my project ,the crash don`t  appear.this bug is find in my release package

Comment: Hi, if you think the crash is only in your release package, you can change the Build Configuration to Release mode, in Edit Scheme. There are some crashes which occur in Release mode and not in Debug mode.

Comment: Try below thing.
Turn off Swift compiler optimisations for the release build, and try it again.
 (In build settings, under Swift Compiler/Code Generation)